# Production specific settings deployment through CI/CD

Tags: cicd

We'd like to push the profile settings and metadata type to production with production specific values. Is there a way deploy only those production specific settings to production via CI/CD?

Comment: What's the setup here? What profile settings and are you talking about a custom metadata type?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves, for example, we have IP whitelisting for APIs, the API clients also have sandbox and different IP address for sandboxes and production client environment. We want to avoid / minimize changing things directly in production and do most of the configurations through CI/CD.

Comment: Another example is the SSL cert we use for Callouts, we have different certs for sandboxes and production. Wondering if there's a way to differentiate the sandbox certs from production certs and deploy them appropriately.

Comment: Do you have any existing tools/processes (github, gearset, ant scripts, etc)?

Comment: Yes we use github, screwdriver (https://screwdriver.cd/) and use ant for deployment.